# Subtracting one arrayList from another arrayList using C#

Tags: c#, windows, development-environment

I need Subtracting one arrayList from another arrayList using c#.
Help me please

Comment: Could you provide more details? Ideally, include an example with input and expected output, along with any code that you've tried so far

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide us with input and your expected output, as well as a detail description of your problem.

Comment: From the **[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1)** *`We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic List<T> class. The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best performance.`*  It has been that way for many, *many* years

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use LINQ for all enumerable manipulations:

```
var a = new []{1,2,3,4,5};
var b = new []{    3,4,5,6,7,8};

var res = a.Except(b).ToList();
//res: 1,2
```

Comment: Do we know what the OP means by "Subtract"?

Comment: Nope. But probably OP just didn't know necessary terms to express problem correctly. In general subtract on sets means just that. Can be wrong about whole thing and should be downvoted, not a big deal.

Comment: I'm wondering if he might have also meant `{ 5, 2, 1 } - { 3, 1, 3 } = { 2, 1, -2 }`?

Comment: @eocron If the question isn't clear enough to answer, **don't answer it**. Post a comment requesting clarification or vote to close.